# C++ Image processing loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, image-processing

I have two grey scale images in txt files, one being a smaller block of the Main image. I have read the images into two different 2d vector matrices.

The Rows and the Columns of the images are:

Main: M = 768 N = 1024

SubImg: R = 49 C = 36

```
int R = 49; int C = 36;     //Sub Image Rows / Columns
int M = 768; int N = 1024;  //Main Image Rows / Columns
```

I want to loop through the Main image by blocks of width: 49 and height: 36 and put each block into an array, so I can compare the array with the Sub image (using Nearest Neighbor Search) to see which block  has the closest result to the Sub image.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the loop to display all of the blocks. When I run the loop only a certain number of block appear and the program clashes.

```
// Testing Main 2D Vector in block format
for (int bx = 0; bx < M; bx += R)
    for (int by = 0; by < N; by += C) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < R; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < C; ++y)
            {
                cout << MainIMG_2DVector[bx + x][by + y] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong.

Thanks

EDIT +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

After debugging

```
_DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
_SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
```

M=768 is not divisible by R=49, the last loop starts with bx=735 (15*49) and should ends to bx=735+48=783 > 768... Same problem in N=1024 and C=36 by=1008 (28*36) to by=1008+35=1043 > 1024. – J. Piquard

If I increase the width and the height, my main image stretch. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is the error that I'm getting _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
   _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;

Comment: Because M=768 is not divisible by R=49, the last loop starts with bx=735 (15*49) and should ends to bx=735+48=783 > 768... Same problem in N=1024 and C=36 by=1008 (28*36) to by=1008+35=1043 > 1024.

Comment: @J.Piquard Thank you for that answer, is there a way around this, do I have to change the height and the width of the Main image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways could be explored:

**Way 1** - change the value `R` (and `C`) to the best divider of `M` (and `N`)

```
int M = 768; int N = 1024;  //Main Image Rows / Columns
int R = 48; int C = 32;     //Sub Image Rows (768=16*48) / Columns (1024=32*32)
```

**Way 2** - prevent `out of range error` in the for-loop exit condition

> For `x`, both conditions `(x < R)` and `((bx + x) < M))` shall be
>   `true`.
>
> And for `y`, both conditions `(y < C)` and `((by + y) < N))` shall be
>   `true`.

```
for (int x = 0; ((x < R)&&((bx + x) < M)); ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; ((y < C)&&((by + y) < N)); ++y)
    {
        if ((bx + x)>=M) {
            std::cout << (bx + x) << (by + y) << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
for (int x = 0; x < R; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < C; ++y)
    {
        if ((bx + x)>=M) {
            std::cout << (bx + x) << (by + y) << " ";
        }
    }
}
```